# Trying to understand and workon SSH. What happens on removing all the ssh ciphers from sshd_config

Tags: server, ssh, openssh, sshd

If we remove all the ssh ciphers from sshd_config file , will it allow to establish ssh connection by all the available ciphers of the current system ? Or there is a specific set which it will allow ? If there is a specific set , how and what is that default set of ssh ciphers. If it starts allowing all the available ssh ciphers then can I assume the list to be same as the output of "ssh -Q cipher" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if no `Ciphers` are specified in `sshd_config` to *limit* the ciphers that may be used, then `sshd` will use all supported, non-deprecated ciphers.

In normal package distributions (you have not modified and built the openssh package yourself), the ciphers supported by `ssh` and `sshd` will be identical, so `ssh -Q cipher` will list the supported `sshd` ciphers (which should be identical as a set to those listed in `man sshd_config`).

Note that `ssh -Q` queries what the client supports; it will not list the ciphers supported by some *remote* machine's `sshd`.  It also will not identify which of those ciphers are *deprecated* and therefore not used by default by the local `sshd`.  The default list for a given installation will be found in the `Ciphers` section of `man 5 sshd_config`; for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,
aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

1. If you do not specify the `Ciphers` in your `sshd_config`, the client will use a default list of allowed ciphers. It is explained in the manual page. In Ubnutu 16.04

> The default is:
>
> ```
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
> aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,
> aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
> ```

2. If you specify some set, for example `Ciphers aes128-ctr`, only this cipher will be used for connections.

The list produced by `ssh -Q cipher` will show the list of all supported ciphers, but not all of them are enabled, because some of them exists only for legacy reasons.